# Android : Difference between BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING and BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING

Tags: android

I want to know the difference between the two flags

```
BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING
```

And

```
BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING
```

I developed an application that uses these two flags, and I expected to see "discharging" when I unplugged the phone from the charger, but instead it simply says "not charging".

What is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from : [Battery is low. Charging current not enough...Is there intent before this message is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404185/battery-is-low-charging-current-not-enough-is-there-intent-before-this-messag)

Some devices (tablets?) consume more power than what can be provided via USB port.

Comment: The post linked to in your answer does not say anything about `BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING`.

Comment: @abeboparebop , But second line is self explanatory about the difference once you gone through the logic. I tried to keep my answer sort and simple and less confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I can find no clear definition of the two in the Android APIs or elsewhere online.

My best guess is that `BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING` indicates that the device is actively draining power, while `BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING` indicates that the device is plugged in but is not receiving enough power to actually charge -- for instance, if it is plugged into a low-power USB port.

However, there are other reports from developers that certain devices never return `BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING`, even when completely unplugged: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-reviews/1AjyPYt0tQs

In particular, the Nexus 7 2013 seems to have this bug (confirmed by personal experience): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=124768.

Presumably, you ran into a similar bug.

Comment: Sigh - I confirm the Nexus 7 bug ;)

Answer (score 0):

The other option for not charging is simply that the battery is full, hence no need for charging or that there is no battery at all.

Comment: Well in this case, the flag would be BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL